# How to embed v8 engine into dll (c++ project)

Tags: embed, v8

I have a questions about embedding v8 into dll,please help me,thanks a lot.

I have a odbgscript.dll plugin project of vs2013 for ollydbg2.01, this dll call v8(version v8-5.6.331) to execute javascript statements. ollydbg.exe call odbgscript.dll. My calling v8 codes in odbgscript.dll as following:

```
#include "v8.h"
using namespace v8

    V8::InitializeICU();                
    V8::Initialize();       

    Isolate::CreateParams create_params;        
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);     
    Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);

    HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);      
    Local<Context> context = Context::New(isolate);     
    Context::Scope context_scope(context);

    Local<String> source = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate,    "'hello'+'world'");
    Local<Script> script = Script::Compile(source);
    Local<Value> result = script->Run();
```

above codes can be compiled successfully by vs2013,but after running ollydbg.exe, execute odbgscript.dll plugin ,ollydbg.exe is aborted and some error tips as following:

Operating system:   6.1.7601, platform 2 (Service Pack 1)
OllyDbg version:    2.01.00
Exception code:     C0000005
Parameters:         00000000 00000000
Exception address:  00000000

Comment: please provide a [mcve]  did you initialize the platform?  did you create an isolate?  I can't tell unless you provide a full example reproducing the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this problem . Different v8 version need different syntax statements. change number you can get corresponding example .

https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/5.6/samples/hello-world.cc